# Visual Basic MsgBox exiting

Tags: vb.net

I created a message box which asks the user if he/she wants to close the application.

I came up with this class:

```
Private Sub closeAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles closeAll.Click
        MsgBox("Do you want to terminate the program?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Close?")
        If MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub
```

If I select "Yes", it works fine as it exits the application successfully. But if "No" is selected, it would still close. Does it really need an "Else" statement to do so?

If it does, I don't know the proper coding for letting the program "not do something".

Can someone help?

Comment: If MsgBox(..) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MsgBox()` is a function that returns the result (`MsgBoxResult` enum) so your code should be:

```
Private Sub closeAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles closeAll.Click
    If MsgBox("Do you want to terminate the program?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Close?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

The way you wrote is you take the value of enum `MsgBoxResult.Yes` and check if it's true. That causes an implicit conversion to a boolean value which is true since the enum value is not zero.